# Qt, MediaScannerConnection does not work on creating folder second time

Tags: android, qt, directory, invisible

To make visible to my folder from Windows with USB connection (MTP) : /storage/emulated/0/MyFolder

I put a dummy file on this folder and use MediaScannerConnection.scanFile to scan this file.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "MyFolder" + File.separator + "dummy.txt");
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { file.toString() }, null, null);
```

All work well at the first time, i see that folder and dymmy file on windows.  But if i delete the whole folder, when folder are re-created, it is seen as a file of 4K on windows.

Is there any cache on this level ? And how can i refresh this cache ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This bug of MTP still persists :

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36956498

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37071807

MediaScannerConnection.scanFile is not a perfect solution.